# How to display a button in the center of the screen?( not the screen in center of the window.)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500+0+0")
startbutton = Button(anchor=CENTER, text="Start",height=1,width=4)
startbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This is my code , button gets displayed only in the center of the x axis.

Comment: `startbutton.pack(expand=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

use tkinter funtions to get the screen size

```
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

then set the location of it